# Probability of picking out at least parts of very large pools?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

I have 100 million unique balls, and 10000 copies of each ball (1 trillion balls in total), and I pick out 500 million randomly without replacement.

What are the chances I pick out at least 50 million unique balls? 100 million?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Assume a binomial distribution because the sample size is very large (even without replacement this is negligible). Then, use the parameters: n(number of trials)= 500 million, p(probability of success)= 1/100 million and x(number of succeses) will vary depending on your question.

Comment: how would that work? shouldn't the probability of success be high at first then drop off as you start picking more and more?

Comment: Yes. But due to the large sample size, the difference in probability is negligible (we are talking hundreds of millions of balls)

Comment: so it only approximates if I have a large number of trials then?

also how would I even evaluate something like 5*10^8 choose 10^8

Comment: Yup if you have a large number of trials, usually you may assume a distribution. As to evaluating it, just write your answer in exact form.. It may be difficult to evaluate if the number is that large

Comment: so why is a binomial distribution better than any other other distributions? I pretty much am looking for just the evaluated number here, even if it's just an estimate, I just don't know of any calculators that are good at handling large numbers